# Why do images haven't smooth edges in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart

The quality of images in Flutter is really bad.

Example:
The edges of the circle are not smooth.
Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

This is the code:

```
      Image.asset(
        "assets/images/circle.png",
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
      ),
```

I have the same problem with many other images, which have round edges despite the orginal images have a very good quality.

Can anybody help?

I looked for two hours on the internet, but maybe I didn't used the right terms to search...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @isherwood how do I do this? Im having the exact same issue with my png files. they look so jagged. i tried filterquality medium and high . nothing worked

Comment: @KaranV, 24-bit PNG is a file type, not a quality setting.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an 8-bit PNG file with no anti-aliasing. Try a 24-bit file with the alpha channel. You'd do this by configuring the save settings in your image editor.